# Histogramas con Matplotlib python, líneas de separación

Tags: python, matplotlib

Estoy graficando un histograma con el siguiente código:

```
# Histograma del MOS
plt.title('MOS')
plt.hist(mos, bins = 60)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
plt.clf()
```

[image]

El problema es que no se ven los bordes en negro de los rectángulos, osea se ve todo pegoteado como en la figura que adjunto.

Esto ocurre igual para cualquier número que use en bins.

Quisiera que se vean las separaciones entre los rectángulos.

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A partir de la versión 2 de Matplolib `edgecolor` está [desactivado por defecto](http://matplotlib.org/2.0.0rc2/users/dflt_style_changes.html#patch-edges-and-color).

Simplemente pasale al constructor este argumento con el color a usar:

```
from random import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


#Datos aleatorios para el ejemplo
mos = [int(random()*100) for _ in range(3000)]

plt.title('MOS')
plt.hist(mos, bins=60, alpha=1, edgecolor = 'black',  linewidth=1)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
plt.clf()
```

**Salida ejemplo:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Funcionó! Gracias!

Comment: Para qué son los parámetros alpha y linewidth?

Comment: `alpha` es la transparencia de las barras (en este caso no hay transparencia) y `linewidht` es el ancho de las lineas  que dibuja para demilitarlas (edge).  Puedes quitarlo si no los vas a modificar, lo importante es `edgecolor` (tambien se le puede pasar como `ec` simplemente). Tambien puedes espaciar las barras usando `rwidth`, por ejemplo `rwidth= 0.9` crea las barras con un 90%  de la anchura, dejando un 10% de separación entre cada barra..